# Logout from Spring security keycloak adapter, but no need to login to access application

Tags: spring, spring-security, keycloak, logout

I have a small problem with my Keycloak Spring security adapter configuration.
I have an application secured by Keycloak via Spring security.
It works pretty well, I can connect without any problem.

My problem is at logout.
When I click the logout button, I am 'logged out', that is, redirected to the login page, Keycloak session cleaned (checked in Keycloak), so everything seems good.
The problem is that when I click to access the application again in a new tab, I don't have the login page displayed, I have direct access to the application.
I debbuged and it seems that the problem is that the Keycloak token is still available and valid in the application, and therefore no need to login again.
I googled a lot, but I don't find any working solution for it.

Here is my logout config :

```
...
.addFilterBefore(keycloakPreAuthActionsFilter(), LogoutFilter.class)
...
.addFilterAt(logoutFilter(), LogoutFilter.class)
...
.logout()
                .addLogoutHandler(keycloakLogoutHandler())
                .logoutUrl("/logout")
                //Allows specifying the names of cookies to be removed on logout success.
                .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                //Configures SecurityContextLogoutHandler to invalidate the HttpSession at the time of logout.
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
...
    @Bean
    public LogoutFilter logoutFilter() throws Exception {
        LogoutFilter logoutFilter = new LogoutFilter("/login.app", keycloakLogoutHandler());
        logoutFilter.setFilterProcessesUrl("/logout");

        return logoutFilter;
    }
...
```

So, my question is : how can I, at logout time, invalidate/delete/clean the Keycloak token present in the application ?

Thank you very much for the help !

Comment: may be this can help ,https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/#logout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, as Harish Gupta point, the solution was to add a simple HttpServletRequest.logout() to make it work completely.

Thank you !

Comment: but application must be check token with keycloak before every request. for example if you logout all session from keycloak ui, you should not authorize with spring